# Explicit homotopy between two maps from $\mathbb{R}P^1$ to $\mathbb{R}P^2$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I am stuck with constructing an explicit homotopy between $f$ and $g$, where $f,g:\mathbb{R}P^1 \to \mathbb{R}P^2$ are the maps defined by $$f[x,y]=[x,y,0]$$ and $$g[x,y]=[x,-y,0]$$

Notation: For $x=(x_1,\dots,x_{n+1})\in S^n$ we write $[x_1,x_2,\dots, x_{n+1}]$ for the corresponding point in $\mathbb{R}P^n$.

What I tried: I tried the "straight line" homotopy $F([x,y],t)=[x,y-2ty,0]$ but realised it doesn't work because the projective plane cannot have $[0,0,0]$.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider

$$f_t(x, y) = [x, (\cos t) y , (\sin t) y].$$

The map is well-defined: If $x = 0$, then $y\neq 0$ and $\cos t $, $\sin t $ can't be both zero.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your help, however just to ask a few things: Do you mean $[x,(\cos (\pi t)y, (\sin \pi t)y]$ instead? (To ensure $f_1(x,y)=[x,-y,0]$.

Comment: Oh yes, of course. Anyway $f_\pi$ will be what you want. @yoyostein